# Measurable with respect to counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

> $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers. Let $(X, A, \mu) = (Y, B, \nu) =
>  (\Bbb N, M, c)$ be the measure space such that $M = 2^N$, and $c$ the
>    counting measure defined by setting $c(E)$ equal to the number of
>    points in $E$ if $E$ is finite and $\infty$ if $E$ is an infinite set.
>    Define $f\colon\Bbb N\times\Bbb N \to\Bbb R$ by setting 
>     $$f(x, y) =  f(n) = \begin{cases} 2-2^{-x},  & \mbox{if }x=y \\
>  -2+2^{-x}, & \text{if $x=y+1$}  \\ 0, & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that $f$ is measurable with respect to the product measure $c\otimes c$. Also, show that $$\int_N [ \int_N f(m,n)dc(m)]dc(n) \ne \int_N [
>  \int_N f(m,n)dc(n)]dc(m).$$
>
> Is this a contradiction either of Fubini’s or Tonelli’s Theorem?

**Solution:**

Then $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty f(x,y) = f(1,1) = 1.5$

but,

$$\sum_{y=1}^\infty\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x,y) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty(2-2^{-y}) + (-2 + 2^{-y-1}) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty2^{-y-1}-2^{-y} = - \sum_{y=1}^\infty 2^{-y-1} = -0.5$$

So, $\ne$.

We cannot remove the hypothesis that $f$ be nonnegative from Tonelli's Theorem or that $f$ be integrable from Fubini's Theorem.

Is this sufficient for the last two? What about the first question?

Comment: **Hint:** Check the entire statement of each theorem. Is $M$ *σ*-finite?

Comment: Can you explain how you compute the iterated integrals? The first one in particular is not clear to me where $f(1,1)$ came from.

Comment: @TuringTester69 I wonder the same thing - I've asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477221/fubinis-theorem-versus-two-different-values-on-double-integrals-question-abou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\Bbb N$ is countable and the only set for which $c\otimes c$ measure is $0$ is the emptyset, the $c\otimes c$ measurable sets of $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ are all the subsets, hence $f$ is measurable.

The measure $c$ is $\sigma$-finite, hence it show we cannot remove the assumption of non-negativeness or integrability.