# Computing iterated integrals over positive integers (question about stack exchange solution)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, product-measure

I am referring to this question: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352562/397536)

How does one go about computing the iterated integrals?

I am confused as to how the first one simplifies to $f(1,1)$ and why the second one has:

$\sum_{y} 2^{-y-1} - 2^{-y} = - \sum_{y} 2^{y-1}$

Any clarification is appreciated.

**Edit 1:** I assume we are supposed to compute each part by taking the sections of $f$, where we fix one variable.

So, for example, the inside part of the first integral is $\sum_{y} f_x(y)$ (where $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$ and $x$ is fixed). For a fixed $x$ this should evaluate to $(2-2^{-x}) + (-2 + 2^{-(x+1)})$ where the first summand is coming from the case where $y=x$ and the second comes from the case where $y=x-1$. In which case, they would evaluate to the same thing.

**Edit 2:** But obviously this *shouldn’t* be the case as we violated the non-negativity requirement of Tonelli’s and I think (from what I’ve gathered from the correct solution) we violated integrability of Fubini’s.