# Fubini's theorem versus two different values on double integrals - question about infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I am stuck trying to understand answer given on [this Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352562/measurable-with-respect-to-counting-measure). Where do both

$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty f(x,y) = f(1,1) = 1.5
$$
and
 $$\sum_{y=1}^\infty\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x,y) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty(2-2^{-y}) + (-2 + 2^{-y-1}) = \sum_{y=1}^\infty2^{-y-1}-2^{-y} = - \sum_{y=1}^\infty 2^{-y-1} = -0.5$$
come from? This might be a basic calculus but why is $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty f(x,y) $ equal to $f(1,1)$? The same question about $\sum_{y=1}^\infty\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: for any given $x$ there are only two values of $y$ for  which $f(x,y)$ is not zero. Just add the values of $f(x,y)$ for these two vales of $x$ and see what you get.

Comment: Um, $0$ I guess?

Comment: @math_beginner Except for $x = 1$, then there is only one $y$ (namely $y = x = 1$) with $f(x,y) \neq 0$. Thus in that order the summation yields $f(1,1)$.